# Why can I not enter the while loop? (Java)

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I want to prompt the user to enter their value within the while loop. The error is caused from trying to receive the user's values using input = kbd.nextInt() and then trying to use that object name in the condition within my while loop (caused a deadlock). Therefore, when trying to run it, the console was blank. Thank you for the help!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  
    
     
    int input = keyboard.nextInt(); 
    
    
    Random generator = new Random(); 
    int num = generator.nextInt(100);
            
    
    int counter = 10;
    
    
    while (input != num && counter > 0 )
    {
    
        System.out.print("Enter your guess at my number ");
        input = keyboard.nextInt(); 
        
        counter--; 
        
    }
        
    //close scanner 
    kbd.close();

}
```

}

Comment: `int input = kbd.nextInt(); int rNum = generator.nextInt(100)+1; int counter = 0; while (input != rNum && counter < 10 )` 1% chance to enter the loop. The random value is 1..100. If you input the wrong number, the loop's condition is not satisfied and the loop will not be entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you use a statement which takes input (in your case - `int input = kbd.nextInt();`) the Java application stops executing right there and waits for a input from the specified source (System.in here). Try executing the code again and this time input a random number which will be the value of input variable. After that the loop will start.
Also, in this case of the game you should change `int input = kbd.nextInt();`  to

```
int input = -1;
```

That will kill the 1 percent chance of the random number being same as the number entered before the loop (game) starts. Or you could put an if condition checking if input and the random number are equal and if they are take a new random number and check again (in a loop).

Answer (score 0):

With the statement `int input = kbd.nextInt();` before the while loop you are already waiting for user input - without prompting the user. I bet you application is waiting for you to enter the first int. Since you are waiting for while loop to start and the application is waiting for you there is a deadlock.

Figure out how to run a debugger to execute your code step by step. It will help a lot.